# Applying a Function within a Function

Tags: functions, functional-style

How do I define a function with a function?

Ok, so lets take a positive integer n and output the result iteratively summing and squaring the integers from 1 to n...

```
myfunc[x_, y_] := (x + y)^2
Fold[myfunc, 1, Range[2, 4]]
21904
```

The above works but how do I then insert this into a function?

```
SquareSum[n_Integer] /; n > 0 :=  ???
```

I am suitably intrigued as to the preferred method of definition in Mathematica.

***Caveat*:** I am working through Wolfram challenges in part to get back up to speed with Mathematica after a long and fruitful sojourn in R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[SquareSum]
SquareSum[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Fold[myfunc, Range[n]]
SquareSum[4]
```

> 21904

**to include *myfunc* in the function definition rather than as an external definition:**

```
ClearAll[SquareSum2, SquareSum3]

SquareSum2[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Fold[Function[{x, y}, (x + y)^2], Range[n]]
SquareSum3[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Fold[(# + #2)^2 &, Range[n]]

SquareSum3[4] == SquareSum2[4] == SquareSum[4]
```

> True

Comment: How do you include myfunc within the function definition of SquareSum rather than as an external definition?

Comment: This also works: `Fold[Through[{Plus, Plus}[##]] & /* Apply[Curry[Times, 2]] /* Times, 
 Range[4]]`.

Comment: +1 for `SquareSum3`

Comment: @kglr - Thank you for your help. It is very much appreciated. You have also taught me some new ways to use Mathematica.

Comment: @Technophobe01, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.